# Sound does not work properly since Win 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, audio, vlc-media-player

I have IDT High Definition Audio Codec installed on my E6420 Dell. When I had Win 7 installed, I was able to direct sound to my speakers. I have the IDT speaker/headphone combination selected as default.

Since I upgraded to Win 10, I am no longer able to get any sound through the speakers (I have the headphone pulled out).

In addition VLC will not play back through the speakers or the headphones.

When I left click on the audio icon, a single slider pot comes up representing the IDT system, but manipulating this makes no difference.

I ran the windows troubleshooter and it fixed some problems, I can now hear Vlc and Skype, and Audacity loaded with no error message, but still no way to get sound through the speakers.

Comment: Try the windows audio settings by typing audio in the start menu and clicking "Manage Audio Devices". Do you know if your windows 7 was 32 or 64 bit. Same goes for windows 10? This may be caused by drivers, so reinstalling them may also help.

Comment: 7 was 64, 10 is Pro, 64 bit.

Comment: Try right clicking on the sound card in device manager and clicking "Update Driver Software..."

Comment: Did that before, did it again, best driver is installed.

Comment: Try an uninstall from device manager. Then click "scan for hardware changes" from the icons in the top of device manager. Windows should automaticly reinstall the driver.

Comment: Audacity and "Groove merchant" or something which substituted for VLC both say they cannot find any audio devices. This is after uninstalling and reinstalling the driver. The only setting that works is "default device" and only the headphones work.

Comment: @Xavierjazz - Have you tried just allowing Windows to install the default driver instead of using the IDT driver + application?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: See this...http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN297969/en

Comment: @Moab: "By default Windows 10 should install the IDT Audio Chipset driver on your computer."

Comment: And I trust W10 to get it right....

Comment: Well, cannot direct sound to the speakers. Thanks all.

Comment: A workaround would be to restart the Windows Audio service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their help. I was finally able to resolve this issue by locating this site:http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/no-sound-7-tips-fix-audio-issues-windows-10/

"3. Update IDT High Definition Audio CODEC
A number of systems may encounter issues with their IDT High Definition Audio CODEC. This can be fixed with a manual driver update which allows us to choose the sound driver we wish to use.

Right-click the Start menu and select Device Manager. Expand the Sound, video games and controllers section. If you spot IDT High Definition Audio CODEC, right-click and select Update Driver Software. In the next panel, select Browse my computer for driver software, followed by Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer. This allows us to select from any drivers pre-installed on our system."

The key was found just below this. It was to do the update in the "Sound, video games and controllers section" rather than the Audio input area.

Again, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Four years later, the accepted solution of 2016 is outdated.

I had the same issue on an older Lenovo Z710 Ideapad after a full reset of Windows. The "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC" had a yellow sign, and I could not get any sound. I found [Audio device missing or cannot find audio device - ThinkPad, ThinkCentre, ThinkStation](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510392-audio-device-missing-or-cannot-find-audio-device-thinkcentre-m720s-m720t) to fix it. Strangely, there were two rather confusing drivers offered when I had followed the steps almost to the end:

- **"High Definition audio controller" (right one) and**
- **"IDT High Definition Audio CODEC" (wrong one!).**

While the accepted solution of 2016 asks you to update with the choice "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC" at this point, surprisingly, this has turned out wrong in my case. Against any intuition, you must not choose the driver with the same name like the device! Instead, you need to strictly follow the Lenovo guide and really install the "High Definition audio controller". You must ignore the warning message that it is recommended not to install this device driver since it cannot be assured that it is compatible with the hardware.

Thus, it is simply a problem with the "High Definition Audio Device Driver", although the device manager shows "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC".

Here is everything as a compact list which I found later, thanks go to https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Problem-with-High-Definition-Audio-Device-Driver/td-p/4470925:

1. Open the Device Manager (type devmgmt.msc in the search box and hit Enter) and right click on IDT High Definition Audio Codec.
2. Select to "Update Driver Software".
3. Click on "Browse my computer for driver software".
4. Click "Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer".
5. Put a check in the box "Show compatible hardware" if not already checked.
6. In the list of devices, click "High Definition Audio".
7. Click "Next".
8. On the Update Driver Warning box, click "Yes" (install the driver).
9. Restart the laptop if prompted. If not prompted, then no need to restart.

*A side-remark: When I first installed "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC" at this point (thinking that the Lenovo guide was outdated), I got a different Audio device name (something like Audio ... Bus or so) and I had to uninstall it using the device manager, then right-click the no-sound error tray icon, and then click on repair, so that I got the former "IDT High Definition Audio CODEC" device name back. And then I installed the "High Definition audio controller" and it worked.*

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading an offical dell driver for your audio from here http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-e6420/drivers/advanced. Please note dell states that this device is:

> Product not tested for Windows 10 upgrade
>
> Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product.
>   If you choose to upgrade, some features, applications, and connected
>   devices may not work as expected.

Comment: The drivers on that page are not compatible with Windows 10, there really isn't any sense in trying them, can you perhaps suggest another solution that is more likely to solve the problem for the author?

Comment: I disagree. They are not tested for windows 10, which doesn't mean they are not compatible. I have installed many windows 7 drivers on windows 8, 8.1, and 10 with no issues.

Comment: "No driver updates found. Your system has the most recent updates"