# issue with lenovo audio - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, thinkpad, realtek-hd-audio

I am having an issue with my lenovo thinkpad since I bought it.

No sound devices are installed
[image]

, so the laptop speaker and microphone are not working (however I am able to use bluetotth speaker and mic)

I was trying to fix this over days with no hope.

I came across this official link showing the realtek
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ee/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t590-type-20n4-20n5/downloads/ds506551

I downloaded the driver, but still not able to see it in the device manager, my question:
[image]

1- how can I install the realtek so that it shows in device manager

Another thing, I tried to update the Intel(R) Display Audio driver as an attempt to install Realtek, I found that there are 3 realtek drivers, and I dont know which one to choose from (or this really a good practice? As the drivers are not marked as compatible)

[image]

Comment: I am having an issue with my lenovo thinkpad since I bought it.    .... Did you contact Lenovo?   Sound works fine on my Lenovo ThinkPads.  Did you update BIOS and Audio Drivers?

Comment: And did you check the "BIOS" (actually UEFI) for some device settings? Some firmwares do allow enabling/disabling some hardware (LAN, WiFi and yes, onboard audio). And, Intel Display Audio has nothing to do with this because it's a different audio device on the graphics subsystem and refers *only* to HDMI/DP audio. And, of course, I have to agree with @John above, why didn't you contact Lenovo?

Comment: I am having an issue with my lenovo thinkpad since I bought it. .... When was this?  It may not be compliant with Windows 7 (stopped coming on computers quite a few years ago)

Comment: thanks for your answers , I am trying to avoid visiting the support because it usually takes long time and I need the laptop so I am keeping it as last options , meanwhile, yes I updated windows and BIOS and made sure that mic is enabled ... it  is windows 10 not windows 7 (i corrected it)

Comment: First, determine if the speakers are being detected within the UEFI hardware diagnostics, as laptop speakers don't require third-party drivers for sound, only the features of the audio chipset. Due to this, it sounds like either the speaker to motherboard cable isn't properly seated or there's a hardware issue with the speakers or speaker wire harnesses. If a device isn't being detected by Device Manager, the motherboard isn't seeing the device, else it would show and be detected either with, or without, a yellow error icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Lenovo Ideapad Z710 as well, see this answer to [Sound does not work properly since Win 10 upgrade](https://superuser.com/a/1607386/1192848). I guess that this issue can come up with laptops that have a dual graphics card which may give way to some kind of dual sound as well.

Thus, following the other answer, leave aside the Realtec sound driver. Just pick the Intel driver. Take: "High Definition audio controller", which is the main trick in the other answer as well.

You must ignore the warning message that it is recommended not to install this device driver since it cannot be assured that it is compatible with the hardware.